# How do I select which columns to load in a Kedro CSVLocalDataSet?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, kedro

I have a `csv` file that looks like

```
a,b,c,d
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
```

and I want to load it in as a Kedro `CSVLocalDataSet`, but I don't want to read the entire file. I only want a few columns (say `a` and `b` for example).

Is there any way for me to specify the list of columns to read/load?

Comment: When asking homework questions, show your best good faith attempt to solve it and tell what problems you are having to give us a better understanding of your intentions, what you might be doing wrong, and your goal. Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions. Please also have a look at [How do I ask and answer Homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSVLocalDataSet uses [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), which takes "usecols" parameter. It can easily be proxied by using `load_args` dataset parameter (all datasets support additional parameters passing via `load_args` and `save_args`):

```
my_cool_data:
  type: CSVLocalDataSet
  filepath: data/path.csv
  load_args: 
    usecols: ['a', 'b']
```

Also note the same parameters would work for any pandas-based dataset.